# 'Hash Sum mismatch'. How to edit /etc/apt/sources.list specifically?

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

When I try to update my *apt-get*:

`$ sudo apt-get update`

The Warning will appear every time like beblow:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages Hash Sum mismatch
```

After searching the solution for this problem, I met one as below:

> For now, I edited /etc/apt/sources.list and updated it with a new
>   mirror which solved the primary issue of not being able to find a
>   candidate package.

However, I don't know how to edit  */etc/apt/sources.list*  specifically. Could you tell me how to edit in detail? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by opening it with a text editor using elevated user privileges. In this example, I use `vim`:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Inside you should see a line like:

```
deb http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
```

The advice is telling you to change the `cn` country code to a different country code mirror. For example, I have the `us` mirror there instead.